# Creating Actor Dimension for Sakila Data Warehouse

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I'm using Sakila sample database to create a data warehouse, to get to understand how data warehouses work.

Here's the structure of the Sakila db: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html. It's about video rental, it should be pretty self-explanatory.

I have one fact table with one measure, which is the payment amount in the `payment` table for each rental. I created for now 3 dimensions, Time, Location and Film dimensions.

Now I want to create an Actor dimension, to answer the question "which actors are the most popular in our rentals?" However after thinking for a bit I got stuck. Here's my problem.

For creating the Film dimension it was easy, each payment was about one film. So in my fact table, for each `payment_id` I had one corresponding `film_id`, which would be the foreign key between my fact table and the Film dimension. But then there's an N-N relationship between films and actors (via table `film_actor`), so I don't know which foreign key to put into my fact table to link to the corresponding actors, because each `payment_id` would need to be linked to 0..n `actor_id`s.

I hope you understand my problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Bridge table.

Here is a Kimball reference, but it uses a difficult example:

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/02/design-tip-142-building-bridges/

A better explanation is here, although the exampled doesn't exactly match your need:

http://www.askjohnobiee.com/2013/08/how-to-bridge-tables-and-many-to-many.html

The best discussion of Bridge tables I know is Chapter 9 of Christopher Adamson's book, "Star Schema - The Complete Reference". Well worth buying if you're building a dimensional warehouse. You'll find it linked from our bookshelf:

http://ajilius.com/bookshelf/

Comment: The weight column in the bridge table isn't mandatory right? In my case with films and actors, I don't actually need a weight column.

Comment: Correct, it is not mandatory, it is only relevant to the example cases.